# Difference between <img> and <picture> regarding responsive images

Tags: html, responsive-design

I'm doing the MDN HTML tutorial, in the responsive images section, I came across this:

```
    <img srcset="elva-fairy-320w.jpg 320w,
             elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
            (max-width: 480px) 440px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg" alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

And this

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg">
  <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva">
</picture>
```

What's the difference between the two? They both pick the image based on device width, right? The MDN page says the second one should be used for `art direction` problems only, I don't know what that means.

When do you use the `<img>` tag along with `srcset` and `sizes` and when do you use `<picture>` along with `<media>`?

Comment: I thought there was already a thread here on SO covering that topic, but I can't find it and I currently don't have time to write an answer for that, but here is an external article you could read [Don’t use <picture> (most of the time)](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/dont-use-picture-most-of-the-time/). Feel free to create an answer out of it.

Comment: @Pete can you link the duplicate?

Comment: Look at the top of the question, there's a massive box with a link in it

Comment: Oh yes, there it is. It wasn't linked immediately.